# The type MockitoAnnotations.Mock is deprecated

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I am mocking a object using `@Mock` annotation

```
@Mock
Customer customer;
```

but the `@Mock` annotation is showing warning

> The type MockitoAnnotations.Mock is deprecated

and my test case is failed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the wrong mock. Try using the below one

`org.mockito.Mock` instead of `org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.Mock`

Comment: thanks it works for me i have imported org.mockito.Mock

Comment: Do we still have to use the MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this) to instantiate the mocks?

Answer (score 43):

use

```java
MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
```

Answer (score 4):

You may consider removing the **deprecated**

```
@BeforeEach
void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

and **replace** it with this rule inside the class

```
@Rule //initMocks
public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();
```

[Source](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-deprecated-mockitojunitrunner)

Comment: The source you linked suggests using the deprecated method as one of its alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but for those who run into this issue today you probably included the wrong dependency. Make sure to add:

`testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.2'`

where it's mockito**2**.

Comment: I managed by using `openMocks(this)`